# The name ... does not exist in the current context

Tags: linqpad

I have a context like this:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Constructeur qui récupère automatiquement la chaîne de connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Nécessaire pour les commandes de migrations de EF > 4.3.</remarks>
        public ScsContext()
            : base(ConfigurationUtility.GetConnectionString())
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructeur qui prend en paramètre une chaine de connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString">Chaîne de connexion.</param>
        public ScsContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
```

I selected my persistence assembly which contains the ScsContext. I've been able to select the ScsContext and I chose the parameterless constructor and then the config file where the connection string is located.

I did a test to see if it could connect.. yes it could.

I can see all the tables in LindPaq but it failed to do any queries.. like Accounts.Take (100) I get the error saying the name 'Accounts' does not exist in the current context.

Any ideas ? I am pretty sure I have the right DLL and everything.

Comment: I've seen this behavior where the `DbSet` was marked `internal`. Make sure the accessibility level of `Accounts` is `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did when I had this problem

```
using (var cntx = new DataContext("Server=LAPTOP\\EXPRESS2012;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
    var users = cntx.Set<User>().ToList();
    users.Dump();
}
```

I also had to add a reference in LinqPad to the assembly that contained my models\entities then added a namespace import. Just press F4 in linqpad and you can see how to add the references and namespace imports. Also, change the language to C# statement.